# spring boot request validations not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

Application background

- Spring boot version 1.5.12
- Java beans generated via swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

**Problem**

The swagger templates created using open API 3.0 were converted to pojos using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin..

Here is the generate pojo

```
public class TestPojo {

  @JsonProperty("isNameValid")
   private Boolean isNameValid = null;

 @Schema(
    required = true,
    description = "Checks if name is Valid "
)
public Boolean isIsNameValid() {
    return this.isNameValid;
}

}
```

Here is the swagger template used

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
title: XM MNOLine Domain Definitions
description: |
version: "V0.0.1"

components:
 schemas:

  TestPojo:
      required:
        - isNameValid
      properties:
        isNameValid:
          type: boolean
          description: |
            Checks if name is Valid
```

In the controller the @Valid annotations don't seem to have any impact..Null or no values for the field "isNameValid" is still processed..

```
 processRequest(@Valid @RequestBody TestPojo request)
```

What am I missing ..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue is already reported ..
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7058

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding it correct then you want your "isNameValid" field to be present in request else throw exception.

So, in order to make your field mandatory in request you will have to annotate it with `@NotNull`.

ex.

```
    public class TestPojo {

         @JsonProperty("isNameValid")
         @NotNull
         private Boolean isNameValid;

         public void setIsNameValid(Boolean isNameValid) {
             this.isNameValid = isNameValid;
         }

         public Boolean isNameValid() {
             return isNameValid;
         }

    }
```

Above code will not allow `null` values for that field i.e. request will need to have `isNameValid` .

I hope it solves your problem.

If I have misunderstood your requirement, let me know and will try to solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Hi, I currently don't have any ongoing project with swagger open api use, so I can't test it, but can you check [Validate spring contracts](https://springframework.guru/using-swagger-request-validator-to-validate-spring-cloud-contracts/) .

I hope this can be helpful, else let me know.

Good luck!

Comment: hey prashantdoshi28, thanks for trying.. I get that adding @notNull will solve the problem but I am generating pojos using openAPI 3.0 spec and swagger code generator .. can you help me as to what the OpenAPI 3.0 definition should be so as to enforce a not null constraint ?

Comment: Hi, please check edited answer, if it can be helpful or not. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @sharpcodes were you able to figure this out? I'm stuck with the same thing. How did you proceed? TIA!